# Minesweeper floodfill algorithm Python

Tags: python, flood-fill, minesweeper

```
def floodfill(col,rowb,neigh,bombpos):
#neigh is number of bombs (neighbors) around the position (row,col)
try:
    neigh[rowb][col]
    bombpos[rowb][col]
    visit[rowb][col]
except IndexError:
    return
#if the position is an isolated position, i.e. there are no bombs adjacent to it;
if neigh[rowb][col] == 0:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (55, 55, 55), (1 + col * 30, 1 + rowb * 30, 28, 28))
    floodfill(col - 1, rowb, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col, rowb - 1, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col + 1, rowb, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col, rowb + 1, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col - 1, rowb-1, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col+1, rowb + 1, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col + 1, rowb-1, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col-1, rowb + 1, neigh, bombpos)
```

I'm trying to recreate the minesweeper flood fill algorithm, so I have a flood fill function in which I recursively pick all the boxes around the ones that have a neighbor value of 0, meaning they are not touching any bombs. I understand why this is an infinite recursion, and that I must somehow use a visit matrix that detects which position has been tested so I can end eventually end the recursion. I have tried implementing a "visit" matrix which would be switched to true for a position (row,col) if the position is used in the recursion, but I could not get it to work at all. How could I implement the visit matrix in this code in order to get the proper flood fill algorithm used in minesweeper?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I found to work in case anyone has the same issue as me, I'm not sure why but using "try:" would stop the recursion for certain cases, so switching to a good-old fashion if not statement is better for setting the boundaries. Then it is simply a matter of setting the visit matrix to false once you "open" a cell.

```
   if not (-1<rowb<size and -1<col<size):
    return
if neigh[rowb][col] == 0 and not visit[rowb][col]:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (55, 55, 55), (1 + col * 30, 1 + rowb * 30, 28, 28))
    visit[rowb][col] = True
    floodfill(col - 1, rowb, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col, rowb - 1, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col + 1, rowb, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col, rowb + 1, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col - 1, rowb - 1, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col - 1, rowb + 1, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col + 1, rowb - 1, neigh, bombpos)
    floodfill(col + 1, rowb + 1, neigh, bombpos)
```